# markerOption didnt move with current marker in google Map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I try to make app that works with google map .in my map i have currentmarker and markeroption,when i move current marker(Blue Point)makes move but markeroption(redflag,with CurrenrtLocation tag)didnt get move with current marker(Blue Point).how can i make markeroption that move with current marker in googlemap.Thanks

[This picture shows when i move current marker move but markeroption didnt move](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTulS.png)

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mapbutton);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);}

@Override

public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    //Initialize Google Play Services
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }
    else {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }

}


    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }



@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        if (location != null) {
            // ---Get current location latitude, longitude---

            Log.d("LOCATION CHANGED", location.getLatitude() + "");
            Log.d("LOCATION CHANGED", location.getLongitude() + "");
            LatLng currentLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            LatLng currentLatLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            Marker currentLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentLocation).title("Current Location"));
            // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLatLng, 15));
            // Zoom in, animating the camera.
            if (!zoomed) {
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15), 2000, null);
                zoomed = true;
            }
            if (!firstPass){
                currentLocationMarker.remove();
            }
            firstPass = false;
            Toast.makeText(this,"Latitude = "+
                            location.getLatitude() + "" +"Longitude = "+ location.getLongitude(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }



public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
public boolean checkLocationPermission(){
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Asking user if explanation is needed
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

            // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

            //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);


        } else {
            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // Permission was granted.
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                        buildGoogleApiClient();
                    }
                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                }

            } else {

                // Permission denied, Disable the functionality that depends on this permission.
                Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other permissions this app might request.
        //You can add here other case statements according to your requirement.
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make currentLocationMarker a class attribute, actually you are removing it just after adding it.

```
class YourActivity extends Activity implements onMapReady {

    private Marker currentLocationMarker;

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location){

        if ( location != null ){
            if ( currentLocationMarker == null ){
                currentLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentLocation).title("Current Location"));
            }else{
                currentLocationMarker.setPosition(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
            }
        }

    }

}
```

**Explanations**

In your code you add a marker the first time the location change, and then each time location change you add a new one and delete it immediatly with :

```
Marker currentLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentLocation).title("Current Location"));
//...
if (!firstPass){
    currentLocationMarker.remove();
}
```

The best thing to do is to keep reference to the marker you create, and instead of removing it a creating a new one, just update its position, that what I'm doing in my code, if marker doesn't exist (currentLocationMarker == null) then create it and keep reference in class. If marker exist (the else) then just update its position.

Comment: can you explain more?